# Random image Grid Issues

Tags: jquery, image

I have created an image grid (using bootstrap mostly) and within that grid are 3 rows of 5 images. I would like them to ONE AT A TIME load randomly but not repeat until all the images have been used. I have an array of 32 images at this time.

I've created a reduced test case with my current code (http://codepen.io/msbtterswrth/pen/MyZXZQ?editors=0010) which is ALMOST there with a few caveats. You'll notice after it fires they all go to the same image (not sure why), but if you change the following lines it works but repeats frequently.

**change this**

```
var random_no = Math.floor(Math.random()*total_images)+1
```

**to**

```
var random_no = Math.floor(Math.random()*32)+1
```

I'm not terribly good at javascript/jquery and have spent the last two days trying all sorts of things i've come across, but this  is the closest solution I've been able to accomplish.

EDIT: I gave up. Am now using this and some js do position the title over it.  http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedResponsiveImageGrid/index2.html

Still interested in an answer though, for future ref.

Comment: when you do console.log(get_prop($(this))); the value is alway 1 and you do `total_images = get_prop($(this));` so `var random_no=Math.floor(Math.random()*total_images)+1` is the same as `var random_no=Math.floor(Math.random()*1)+1`

Comment: Also `'http://centretek-drupal.centreteksolutions.net/sites/default/files/images/culture-'+store_random+'.jpg';` is the same as `settings.path+store_random+'.jpg';` so in both cases you are getting the same `new_src` is it supoust to be like that?

Answer (score 0):

You could test with this version the issue I detected is that sometimes the `this` object repeats and it changes the src of the same image...

```
setInterval(function () {
    var $flippers = $("section.culture img"),
    qtFlippers = $flippers.length;

    $flippers.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*qtFlippers)).randomize({
        path : 'http://centretek-drupal.centreteksolutions.net/sites/default/files/images/culture-'
    });
}, 500);


/*jQuery RANDOMIZER*/
(function($){

  $.fn.randomize = function(options){

    var new_src,
    settings = $.extend({
                path : 'http://centretek-drupal.centreteksolutions.net/sites/default/files/images/culture-'
            }, options);
    count = 0,
    src_storage = [];

    /*this.each(function(){
        total_images = get_prop($(this));
    });*/


      return this.each(function(){
    new_src = generate_src();
    //console.log($("img")[1].src);
    for(i=0; i<$("img").length; i++){
        if($("img")[i].src == new_src){
        //if(document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].getAttribute("src") == new_src){  
           new_src = generate_src();
          i = 0;
        } 
    }
    this.setAttribute("src",new_src);
});

    // function to check for images that maybe repeated .
    /*function get_prop(current){
        var current_src = current.attr('src');
        if ($.inArray(current_src , src_storage) === -1) {
            src_storage.push(current_src);
        }
        return src_storage.length;
    }*/

    //function to generate a random number
    function generate_random(){
        var random_no = Math.floor(Math.random()*32)+1
        return random_no;
    };

    // function to generate a new src for the selected images
    function generate_src(){
        var store_random = generate_random(),
            new_src;
        if (store_random >= 10) {
            new_src =  'http://centretek-drupal.centreteksolutions.net/sites/default/files/images/culture-'  + store_random + '.jpg';
        } else{
            new_src = settings.path + store_random + '.jpg';
        }
        return new_src;
    }
  }

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: remember to fix your code at : `var random_no=Math.floor(Math.random()*total_images)+1`

Comment: where should i add this to my script? which lines do i replace?

Comment: I updated my pen with your code and still got duplicates and had to change the total images to 32. could you for it and show me how you got it to work?